# Analysis fails on PHP project with NullPointerException, fails on foreach($arrayOfArrays as list($item1, $item2)) {}

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

Example code:

```
foreach ([["1", "2"], ["one", "two"]] as list($one, $two)) {
    print $one." => ".$two.PHP_EOL;
}

//expected:
// 1 => 2
// one => two
```

Removing similar from my source file allowed the analysis to complete where it didn't before:

```
foreach ($criteria->getObjects() as list($objectTypeId, $objectId)) {
    //...
}
```

This is perfectly valid PHP and runs just fine.

Comment: Could you provide the stack trace of the Null Pointer Exception please ?

Comment: Also which version of the PHP plugin are using ?

Comment: version 2.6 (installed via update centre)

Comment: Too big for comment here, here a gist:
https://gist.github.com/scottaubrey/e7204b67d7f2be33bc03

Answer (score 0):

So here is the related ticket [SONARPHP-472](http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARPHP-472). It will be fixed in next version 2.7 of the PHP Plugin. The only workarounds in the mean time are:

- deactivate the rule
- exclude file from the analysis